# Python: timezone.localize() not working

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I am having some issues getting `timezone.localize()` to work correctly. My goal is to grab today's date and convert it from CST to EST. Then finally format the datetime before spitting it out. I am able to format the date correctly, but the datetime is not changing from CST to EST. Additionally when I format the date I don't see the text representation of the timezone included.

Below I have listed out a simple program I created to test this out:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
#Test script

import threading
import datetime
import pexpect
import pxssh
import threading
from pytz import timezone
import pytz

est = timezone('US/Eastern')
curtime = est.localize(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"))
#test time change
#curtime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")

class ThreadClass(threading.Thread):
  def run(self):
    #now = (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(0, 3600))
    now = (datetime.datetime.now())
    print "%s says Hello World at time: %s" % (self.getName(), curtime)

for i in range(3):
  t = ThreadClass()
  t.start()
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a `)` in your `curtime = ...` line.

Comment: thank you, sorry I typed up a quick example to ask my question.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`.localize()` takes a naive datetime object and interprets it *as if* it is in that timezone. It does *not* move the time to another timezone. A naive datetime object has *no* timezone information to be able to make that move possible.

You want to interpret `now()` in your *local* timezone instead, then use `.astimezone()` to interpret the datetime in another timezone:

```
est = timezone('US/Eastern')
cst = timezone('US/Central')
curtime = cst.localize(datetime.datetime.now())
est_curtime = curtime.astimezone(est).strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")

def run(self):
    print("%s says Hello World at time: %s" % (self.getName(), est_curtime))
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, I actually tried something similar before but I  did not `localize()` the time  before I tried to change the timezone (`astimezone()`). I also was applying the `strftime()` when I was `localize()`ing the time. It seems beside having a understanding of `localize()` and `astimezone()` the order in which the date is formatted matters too, thank you again.

Comment: I had to use `pytz.timezone()` instead of `timezone()`

Comment: @AnonymousUser: then your code doesn't include the `from pytz import timezone` line that is used in the question.

Comment: **@MartijnPieters** That was the problem. I wrote: `import pytz`.

Answer (score 23):

Use `cst.localize` to make a naive datetime into a timezone-aware datetime.

Then use `astimezone` to convert a timezone-aware datetime to another timezone.

```
import pytz
import datetime

est = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
cst = pytz.timezone('US/Central')
curtime = cst.localize(datetime.datetime.now())
curtime = curtime.astimezone(est)
```