# How do I print my timezone hour instead of timezone info with strftime in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to print a date/hour with my local timezone settings.

I have already successfully changed the timezone on the date object, but when I print it, the hour isn't changed. The most I can get is the the TZ info on the date/hour?

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from pytz import timezone
import pytz

localtz = timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')

my_date = datetime(2019, 8, 14, 17, 55)
print(my_date)
print(my_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))

my_tz_date = localtz.localize( my_date )
print(my_tz_date)
print(my_tz_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))

-- produces --

2019-08-14 17:55:00
14/08/2019 17:55:00
2019-08-14 17:55:00-03:00
14/08/2019 17:55:00
```

What I want is for the above code to produce "14/08/2019 12:55:00", like it does on most other programming languages. How do I achieve this in Python?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15642065/4046632

Comment: Don't you mean it should be `14/08/2019 21:55:00` instead (vs `14/08/2019 12:55:00`)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way (I am assuming you mean you expect the final result to be `14/08/2019 21:55:00` instead):

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

localtz = timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')
my_date = datetime.strptime("14/08/2019 17:55", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

print(my_date)
print(my_date.astimezone(timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')).strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"))
print(my_date.astimezone(timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')).strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %Z"))
```

The output:

```
2019-08-14 17:55:00                                                                                                                                                                
14/08/2019 21:55                                                                                                                                                                   
14/08/2019 21:55 -03
```