# How to convert datetime.time object coming from psycopg2 to specific time zone?

Tags: python, datetime, psycopg2

My database returns a value `datetime.time(13, 0, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None))` that I store in `my_dt_object`.

How can I convert its timezone to Europe/Zurich, so that `my_dt_object.strftime('%H')` gives `15`? (considering the current offset of +02 to UTC?

This is what I tried:

```
zurich = pytz.timezone("Europe/Zurich")
zurich.localize(my_dt_object)
```

throws:
ValueError: Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)

```
zurich.localize(my_dt_object.replace(tzinfo=None))
```

throws: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Aaaand...

```
my_dt_object.replace(tzinfo=zurich).strftime('%H')
```

still gives

```
13
```

Comment: Have you seen this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641898/python-timezone-localize-not-working ?

Comment: No.. but I can't really interpret the accepted answer either, how would I apply this to my problem? Maybe you can answer the question! :-)

Comment: What is the data type for field in the database?  What is `TimeZone` set to in database? In `psql` `show timezone;` will return the time zone. What is the query you are using to get the result? **Add as update to question**

Comment: The bigger issue, that I just noticed is that you are working with `datetime.time` and `time` do not work well with  time zones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long winded way to do this:

```
import pytz
import datetime

zurich = pytz.timezone('Europe/Zurich')
dt = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
utc_offset = zurich.utcoffset(dt).seconds/3600 

t = datetime.time(13,0,tzinfo=pytz.utc)
t
datetime.time(13, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)                                                                                                                                                                                           

t = t.replace(tzinfo=None)                                                                                                                                                                                              
t                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
datetime.time(13, 0)

zurich_t = t.replace(hour=t.hour+int(utc_offset))

zurich_t                                                                                                                                                                                                                
datetime.time(15, 0)

zurich_t.hour                                                                                                                                                                                                           
15
```

Though this would probably easier to do in the database:

```
select '13:00+0'::timetz at time zone 'europe/zurich';
timezone   
-------------
 15:00:00+02
```

This assumes the field is `timetz` and the `TimeZone` on the server is UTC.